# Get the authenticated user object from WSO2 Identity server

Tags: wso2, single-sign-on, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to implement the SSO Based SAML2 of WSO2 identity server,now from the given example [here](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/people/suresh/saml2/saml2-demo/bin-dist/saml2.demo.war) of IS documentation ,It seems that from the identity server, I only can get the username from SAMLresponseMessage,  I wonder if I can get the whole user object?
can I get the API for Identity server development?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can get specific attributes. A detailed explanation about that can be found [here](http://sureshatt.blogspot.com/2012/11/getting-user-claims-over-saml-sso-token.html).

Answer (score 1):

Just see repose from Adrian.  The link that Adrian has shared it useful....

Yes you can.  Here, you want to use basic attribute profile and get the user attribute from SAML response.  In identity server SP registration page,  you would see check box to enable "attribute profile"  then you can define the claims that must be sent over SAML response.